# How to install a Windows desktop under Wine

Tags: windows, wine

Once I have installed Linux and Wine, how can I get a Windows desktop (you know, a  relaxing view of green rolling hills and a bluer than blue sky) with Windows menus (if at all)?

Comment: You don't, Wine is not an emulator, you run Windows apps directly as if they were native. And the "green rolling hills" are WinXP only.

Answer (score 2):

Run `winecfg`, then go to the graphics tab and activate `Emulate a virtual desktop`.

The details (like the background pic) can be set at `win.ini` file, in your `.wine` directory.

You'll have to get that background pic from somewhere. It is not included in Wine, but it can be found at several places online.

Answer (score 0):

Wine stands for "Wine Is Not an Emulator", and you are asking for an emulator. Several options exist (such as Virtualbox, which is in the distro repos for at least the debian and arch branches).

You cannot install windows via wine and expect it to run properly. Instead, you need to virtualize a system, and install windows on that system. [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads), [Qemu](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page), and [VMware](http://www.vmware.com/)(non-free) are all options that may interest you.

Comment: -1 Wine is not an amulator, but that does not mean you can't run an emulator on it. Indeed, this is a standard feature.